# Unable to call Realm.createAllFromJson on an Object that has RealmList<RealmString>

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-list

I want to save products directly from json file to `Realm`. I am doing this currently.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        try {
                            realm.createAllFromJson(Product.class, inputStream);
                            realm.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

My `Product.class` has `RealmList<RealmString>` variable, when I parse `Product.class` from server data it works fine as I registered a `Gson` type adapter for `RealmString` in `Retrofit` Configuration.

I want to save all Products from `R.raw.products.json` by calling `realm.createAllFromJson` but I am getting **"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"**

How can I fix this? Is there a way to set type adapter on `RealmConfiguration`?

My JSON file is

```js
[  
   {  
      "title":"some title",
      "product_type":"Recipe",
      "image":"some_url",
      "images":[  
         "image1",
         "image2",
         "image3"
      ]
   }
]
```

And Product class is as follows

```
public class Product {
    private String title;
    private String product_type;
    private String image;
    private RealmList<RealmString> images;
}
```

So essentially `Realm.createAllFromJson` is unable to parse `images` from `json` to `RealmList<RealmString>`

Comment: what is your JSON input? and the definition of the `Product` class?

Comment: Well of course, `images` is a list of strings (primitive) and not a list of objects that have a `value` field

Comment: Yes, to overcome this I can add a type adapter in Gson configuration, but how can I tell Realm to treat this as a RealmString?

Comment: You can't. Use gson.